# How to join two table to display sales for each id

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I was trying to display the total sale of each id by combining the two table by using the id. I have two table 1. user table, 2. sales table

```
//user table

--------------
| id  | name  |
---------------
|  1  | yuki  |
|  2  | soman |
---------------


// sales table

--------------
| id  | total|
---------------
|  1  | 300  |
|  2  | 23   |
|  1  | 500  |
---------------
```

With my query it only display 1 sale witch is sales for yuki.

```
SELECT i.name,SUM(ROUND(s.total),2)) AS sales
FROM user i
INNER JOIN sales s
ON i.id = s.id
--------------
| name | sales|
---------------
| yuki | 800  |
---------------
```

I want to display the output like this, what did I missed from my query?

```
--------------
| name | sales|
---------------
| yuki | 800  |
|soman | 23   |
---------------
```

Comment: Add `GROUP BY i.name` at the end. As it is your query is malformed but MySQL accepts it (and runs it!). Without the `GROUP BY` the query should be rejected, because... it produces the confusion you are just asking about.

Comment: got it thank you! I wish u put it in the answer section so I can tick your answer. Thank you for highlighting it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query needs a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT u.name, SUM(ROUND(s.total),2)) AS sales
FROM user u
INNER JOIN sales s ON s.id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Such error is much easier to spot when sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled.

As an alternative, you might want to consider a correlated subquery, which avoids outer aggregation (it actually behaves like a `LEFT JOIN`, which is - probably - closer to what you want):

```
SELECT u.*, 
    (SELECT SUM(ROUND(s.total),2)) FROM sales s WHERE s.id = u.id) AS sales
FROM user u
```

Side note: `user` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name. Consider using something else, such as `users` for example.